# Manipulating dynamic controls c# form application

Tags: c#, controls

In an application there are panels made at run time. In order to access the panel named myTestPanel I use controls.find, which makes an array that I have to loop through. Is there a better way? Can I publicly declare some panels by name so that I can just manipulate the name as though they were added through the form designer?

This is my code inside of the namespace.

```
    private void mnuForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel myTestPanel = new Panel();
        myTestPanel.Top = 0;
        myTestPanel.Left = 0;
        myTestPanel.Width = this.Width;
        myTestPanel.Height = this.Height;
        myTestPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        myTestPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
        myTestPanel.Name = "myTestPanel";
        myTestPanel.Click += new EventHandler(myTestPanel_Click);
        Controls.Add(myTestPanel);
        myTestPanel.Show();
    }

    private void myTestPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myTestPanel = Controls.Find("myTestPanel", true);
        foreach (var ReallyStupidWayToDoThis in myTestPanel)
        {
            Controls.Remove(ReallyStupidWayToDoThis);
            ReallyStupidWayToDoThis.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array of Panel, then loop through that array to add each pannel into UI
And when you want to access one of them, just access it through the array.
By this way, you don't have to "Find" the control, but directly access it through Index of array.

Comment: I'm sure I sound really dumb, but where and how do I declare it publicly? I don't really need an array. Ideally I could declare Panel mytestpanel = new panel() and set it's properties publicly and then call it with controls.add() inside the even that I want to call it.